# spring-data-elasticsearch and update

Tags: elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

i'm using spring-data-elasticsearch to do CRUD operations.

I have a custom Repository that extends ElasticsearchRepository.

Ultimately ElasticsearchRepository extends CrudRepository which implies updating an existing record is possible.

The question is, how do you accomplish this?  I haven't found a method called "update()"

I thought doing the following would work (code stolen from https://github.com/BioMedCentralLtd/spring-data-elasticsearch-sample-application)

```
    //create
    Book book = new Book();
    book.setId("123455");
    book.setName("Spring Data Elasticsearch");
    book.setVersion(System.currentTimeMillis());
    repository.save(book);

    //update
    book.setName("THIS IS A COMPLETELY NEW TITLE");
    repository.save(book);
```

However the 2nd save throws an InvocationTargetException

Examining it with the debugger shows:

```
[book][0] [book][123455]: version conflict, current [1447792071681], provided [1447792071681]
```

The Book object looks like:

```
@Document(indexName = "book",type = "book" , shards = 1, replicas = 0, indexStoreType = "memory", refreshInterval = "-1")
public class Book {

    @Id
    private String id;
    private String name;
    private Long price;
    @Version
    private Long version;

    public Map<Integer, Collection<String>> getBuckets() {
        return buckets;
    }

    public void setBuckets(Map<Integer, Collection<String>> buckets) {
        this.buckets = buckets;
    }

    @Field(type = FieldType.Nested)
    private Map<Integer, Collection<String>> buckets = new HashMap();

    public Book(){}

    public Book(String id, String name,Long version) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.version = version;
    }

    getters and setters removed for space
```

}

My Repository code is even simpler:

```
import org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.entities.Book;
import org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.repository.ElasticsearchRepository;

public interface BookRepository extends ElasticsearchRepository<Book, Long> {

}
```

Do I have to provide an update method?

EDIT:

Nevermind.  I changed the update to:

```
    //update
    book.setName("THIS IS A COMPLETELY NEW TITLE");
    book.setVersion(System.currentTimeMillis());
    repository.save(book);
```

and it updated the record.

Comment: do u found any solution for it?

Answer (score 2):

You can use UpdateQuery and ElasticSearchTemplate to update any partial document. e.g

```
    final UpdateRequest updateRequest = new UpdateRequest();
    updateRequest.index(mainIndexName);
    updateRequest.type(typeName);
    updateRequest.id(id);
    updateRequest.doc(XContentFactory.jsonBuilder().startObject()
                        .field("accountType", accountType)
                        .endObject());
    final UpdateQuery updateQuery = new UpdateQueryBuilder().withId(id)
                        .withClass(<DocumentClass>).withUpdateRequest(updateRequest).build();
    UpdateResponse updateResponse =  elasticSearchTemplate.update(updateQuery);
```

Comment: Can you share elasticSearchTemplate object creation code?

Comment: You can just have Spring @Autowire it

Answer (score 2):

The second update fails because you're trying to update an entity whose version hasn't changed. The error message you're getting is ES telling you, "hey, you can't save the same version twice!" Try this:

```
//create
Book book = new Book();
book.setId("123455");
book.setName("Spring Data Elasticsearch");
book.setVersion(System.currentTimeMillis());
repository.save(book);

//update
book.setName("THIS IS A COMPLETELY NEW TITLE");
book.setVersion(System.currentTimeMillis()); // you're saving a new version
repository.save(book);
```

Comment: @JishnuPrathap version is a member of the class Book defined above, in OP's question

Answer (score 1):

I updated indexed document as follows code snippet:

```
        IndexRequest indexRequest = new IndexRequest(INDEX_NAME,INDEX_NAME,docid);
        indexRequest.source(fldName, fldValue);
        UpdateRequest updateRequest = new UpdateRequest();
        updateRequest.index(INDEX_NAME);
        updateRequest.type(INDEX_NAME);
        updateRequest.id(docid);
        updateRequest.doc(indexRequest);
        try {
            UpdateResponse res=client.update(updateRequest).get();
            logger.info("update es {}:{}",fe,res.getGetResult());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("update",e);
            throw e;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the ElasticSearch is a similar to the JSON storage:

```
if(exist) {
    update it;// push json to cover it
} else {
    add it;// new save();
}
```

It will update the JSON when Id/Entity is exist, or it will add it.

Answer (score 0):

```
 XContentType contentType = 
org.elasticsearch.client.Requests.INDEX_CONTENT_TYPE;
public XContentBuilder getBuilder(User assign){
 try {
    XContentBuilder builder = XContentFactory.contentBuilder(contentType);
     builder.startObject();
     Map<String,?> assignMap=objectMap.convertValue(assign, Map.class);
              builder.field("assignee",assignMap);
     return builder;
    } catch (IOException e) {
            log.error("custom field index",e);
 }
  IndexRequest indexRequest = new IndexRequest();
    indexRequest.source(getBuilder(assign));
    UpdateQuery updateQuery = new UpdateQueryBuilder()
                                    .withType(<IndexType>)
                                    .withIndexName(<IndexName>)
                                    .withId(String.valueOf(id))
                                    .withClass(<IndexClass>)
                                    .withIndexRequest(indexRequest)
                                    .build();
```

Comment: Would you add more description?