# Optimistic lock in Spring data for ElasticSearch doesn't work

Tags: java, elasticsearch, spring-data, versioning

Does Spring Data for ElasticSearch support document versioning via @Version?
Seems no. If doesn't support, how to do it properly?

Example:

ElasticSearchConfig:

```
@Configuration
public class ElasticSearchConfig extends AbstractElasticsearchConfiguration {

    @Override
    public RestHighLevelClient elasticsearchClient() {
        String host = "localhost"; int port = 9200;
        try {
            System.out.println("ElasticSearch host: " + host + ", port: " + port);
            ClientConfiguration clientConfiguration = ClientConfiguration.builder()
                    .connectedTo(host + ":" + port)
                    .build();
            return  RestClients.create(clientConfiguration).rest();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Entity:

```
@Document(indexName = Ent.INDEX_ENTITY, type = "_doc")
public class Ent {
    public static final String INDEX_ENTITY = "entity";
    @Id
    public String id;
    public String data;
    public Ent(String data) {
        this.data = data;
    }
    @JsonIgnore
    public long version;
    public Ent setData(String arg) {
        this.data = arg;
        return this;
    }
}
```

Test App:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class App {

@Autowired
ObjectMapper objectMapper;
@Autowired
protected ElasticsearchOperations elasticsearchOperations;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(App.class, args);
}

@Autowired
EntRepository entRepository;

@PostConstruct
public void testUpdate() throws Exception {
    Ent ent = entRepository.save(new Ent("some data"));
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        update(ent.setData("data-"+System.currentTimeMillis()));
        System.out.println("version = " + ent.version);
    }
}

public Ent update(Ent ent) throws JsonProcessingException {
    UpdateQuery updateQuery = new UpdateQuery();
    updateQuery.setIndexName(Ent.INDEX_ENTITY);
    updateQuery.setId(ent.id);
    updateQuery.setType("_doc");
    updateQuery.setUpdateRequest(
            new UpdateRequest()
                    .version(1)
                    .versionType(VersionType.EXTERNAL_GTE) // doesn't affect actually...
                    .doc(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(ent), XContentType.JSON)
    );
    UpdateResponse updateResponse = elasticsearchOperations.update(updateQuery);
    ent.version = updateResponse.getVersion();
    return ent;
}

}
```

so, i'm getting output:

```
version = 2
version = 3
version = 4
```

but it never fails although I set
    new UpdateRequest().version(1)

So how to do so that it fails if version is not as expected (or lower than expected) ?

Comment: What `@Version` are you referring to?  Is that an annotation?  In what?

Comment: Annotation for optimistic locking, using in entities 
org.springframework.data.annotation.Version
```public @interface Version {
}```

Comment: The answer to your question is Yes.  See https://stackoverflow.com/a/44976463/139985 for an example.

Comment: The example I linked to shows external versioning.  If you have a specific problem with doing internal versioning, post your code so that someone can look at it.  (The fact that your code apparently does not work is NOT evidence that document versioning is not supported.  You are probably just doing something wrong.)

Comment: somewhy i don't see field '_version'... I see only "version" inside document:
```      {
        "_index" : "indexname",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "1111",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "name" : "my name",
```

Comment: but... seems ES automatically updates field 'version' inside document...

Comment: I don't see external version check is working, although in documentation it's stated: `Also, instead of checking for an exact match, Elasticsearch will only return a version collision error if the version currently stored is greater or equal to the one in the indexing command. `
Even if I pass decreased version - no errors returned by update...

Comment: You need to post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  I think that we won't be able to help you without one.

Comment: here it is https://drive.google.com/file/d/1xy77-tXkj8lbxLMlLlbd9FHibQLQA050/view?usp=sharing

as you see in code, I set version = 1 always but update succeeds anyway. and version incremented.
I tried versionType = EXTERNAL_GTE, but this haven't changed anything

Comment: Sorry, but a minimal reproducible example needs to be in the question, not in a linked document on some external service.  And you need to describe what you are demonstrating / reproducing in the question too.  (Is that Google drive file still going to be there in 20 years time?)

Comment: Are you using SpringData 3.2.6?

Comment: 3.2.5.RELEASE. But it's using only for `save`, not for `update`.

Comment: OK, let me rephrase that.  What version of SpringData are you using for the code that you showed us ... which is doing updates.

Comment: spring-data-elasticsearch version = 3.2.5.RELEASE

Comment: (actually i thought UpdateQuery is from ElasticSearch, but I've checked and yes it's from spring-data)

Comment: I ran out of time last night.  People need to sleep.  Now I'm working.